Why would address of objects inside a std::vector change?
I have the following code
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
struct Foo {
    int value = 0;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Foo> objs;
  for (int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++) {
      objs.push_back(Foo{.value = idx});
      std::cout << "address: " << &(objs.back()) << "\n";
  }
  
  std::cout << "=======\n";
  for (const auto& obj: objs) {
      std::cout << "address: " << &(obj)<< "\n";
  }
}

Now, I expect the object address are the same, but apparently they are not, see below for a screenshot.
How do I understand this? Are the objects moved/relocated internally by the std::vector class somehow?


Because vectors may need to reallocate memory as they grow. Reallocation causes the addresses of all objects in the vector to change. If this is undesireable you should look at the reserve method which allows you to expand a vector upto the given size without reallocation occurring. Eg. if you add objs.reserve(5) between lines 11 and 12, no addresses should change.

Some general reading on the topic and when it happens: Iterator invalidation rules for C++ containers

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Even when there is no reallocation, inserting an object at the back of a vector changes the address of the back() element because the previous back() element, which hasn't moved, is no longer at the back; the new element is the back() element.
